# Imported obj file textures look dull, colors not as they should be

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGAjy.jpg)I'm not new to Blender but this is a new problem for me.

I have bought, downloaded and imported some plant models in to blender and the colours are not appearing as they should, not black but dull, muted versions of the colour they are supposed to be, the models had bright colours on CG trader, purple, white and yellow flowers.

It isn't a lighting issue, I am using an HDRI and adding a sun lamp doesn't improve it. I have had to adjust the alphas before so have tried connecting the alpha to alpha in the base colour shader and changing the texture to alpha clip mode but this hasn't done much but the flowers did flash brighter for a second so I assume I'm doing something wrong with the alpha.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have been trying to change the shader and suspect you might be doing something wrong there, why don't you show us at least one screenshot of your shader setup? Apart from that, how are your _Color Management_ settings? AgX can look a bit flat... and for the lighting... well, just saying you are using "an" HDRI is not really saying much. I have very very different HDRIs here and some of them produce a dull lighting, so... I guess you cannot share the file for closer inspection since you bought the model.

Comment: I've added images for shader set up for the plant texture.

Comment: Also an image showing the colour the flowers are supposed to be (same albedo). It isn't a lighting issue there something up with the plant models. Frustrating that is just probably a click away but struggling to get my head around it and unfortunately working to deadlines!

Comment: Sorry, which image is the one showing the flowers how they are supposed to be? The one at the bottom with the pink wall? The flowers are the same there. Overlay one image with the other in something like PS and set the layer blend to "difference" - the flowers are almost all black. Just almost, because the surface of course reflects a different background. Or the viewport above the shader? Well, this is just the material preview, no real shading or shadows, no real effect from the environment in any way... can't compare that.

Comment: Another thing is: you have plugged either a normal map(?) or a bump map(?) into the _Normal_ input (the texture name says both, normal and bump). What is it, a normal or a bump map? Although in this setup it should not matter since you have set the _Strength_ to 0.000

Comment: They aren't the same. The only thing i changed between the two images is the pink background to show that is the colour they are supposed to be. They are both full renders in cycles not material preview. Ive re done the image to show the true texture colour they are supposed to be (put the petal texture on a cube) and it renders much brighter with no further changes.

Comment: I haven't changed the bump/normal settings at all that's how the texture came in so don't know which it is. it doesn't seem to matter anyway as you say. Really appreciate your input on all this.

Comment: It was not really obvious that the pink background should show the color of the flowers... and the flowers themselves look the same in both images, that's what I meant. And I know these are full renders, the preview I was talking about was the screenshot with the viewport over the shader nodetree. Does the _Render Preview_ in the viewport look the same like the actual render? Are there any lights disabled for render...? I don't know, without inspecting the file I need my crystal ball to find the issue I guess.

Comment: Found it! looks like the texture came in with a default transmission of 1. That's sorted it. Thanks for your comments. I wouldn't have kept looking without it.

Comment: Actually I did not pay attention to the _Transmission_ value unfortunately. You suspected an alpha problem in your question but that looked all fine to me. Glad you found it. You can write this as a short answer and later after some grace period accept it yourself.

Comment: You can also set the specular to 0.5 if you want a more realistic look.